# The restriction $\sigma|K$ is in $Gal(K/k)$

Tags: galois-theory

> If $K$ is Galois over $k$ and $F$ an arbitrary extension of $k$ then I know $KF$ is Galois over K, but if $\sigma\in Gal(KF/F)$ why is then $\sigma|K\in Gal(K/k)$

What is to show here, that $\sigma|K$ remains at least $k$ fixed ? It reminds me of the second isomorphism theorem

Comment: Since $\sigma$ keeps $F \supseteq k$ fixed, it must keep $k$ fixed as well, must it not?

Comment: @Arthur but $F$ is not a subfield of $K$, that doesnt affect anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(KF/F)$, then
$$\sigma(x)=x \quad\forall x \in F$$

Since $k$ is a subset of $F$, it follows that 
$$\sigma(x)=x \quad\forall x \in k$$

In particular, if $K/k$ is a finite extension, you get $\sigma\vert_K \in \mathrm{Gal}(K/k)$.

Comment: thanks a lot. why do you exclude the infinite case ?

Comment: $\sigma \in Gal(K/k)$ means that $K = \sigma(K)$ and $\sigma(x) = x$ for $x \in k$. So you have to show that $K = \sigma_{| K}(K)$

Comment: @user314 : in the finite case, $\sigma\vert_K : K \to K$ is an injective $k$-linear map, hence surjective (since $[K:k]< \infty$). In the infinite case, this might fail.

Comment: I think this holds even for infinite (algebraic) Galois extensions: $\sigma\vert_K(K) = \sigma(K) \subseteq K$, and $\sigma^{-1}(K) \subset K$ because $\sigma^{-1}\vert_K$ is a $k$-embedding from $K$ to $KF \subset \overline k$ (actually to $K$, since $K/k$ is normal). Therefore $K =\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(K)) \subset \sigma(K)$.